# Duration of Initial Quality Check period for "Scientific Report" Journal

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I have submitted a manuscript to Scientific Reports at the "Initial Technical Check Stage." So please give me an idea of how long it usually takes for this stage to be over.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Allure Thanks a lot! My paper is on its checking way.. please pray...I'm so worried!!